# Folder appears with wrong name in explorer

Tags: windows, registry, explorer

So I am accidentally moved my downloads folder as the User directory. I was able to reverse this change and get the downloads folder to be within the User directory.

However, I am left with a problem, in explorer, the User directory (Fishsticks in the cmd window) has been left labeled as Downloads. I am wondering if there is anyway, by changing registry values or otherwise, to relabel the folder so that it appears with the write name in explorer.

Link to image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WKUe.png

I am aware that it is not possible to rename the folder, I just want it to appear with the right name.

Comment: This question is more appropriate for superuser.com

Comment: My apologise, I am still quite foreign to using the stack exchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit or delete the hidden `desktop.ini` file in `c:\Users\yourusername\`, specifically the line that starts with `LocalizedResourceName=` needs to be removed.